# iOS - GameKit / Core Data transmission - Packaging and Repackaging

Tags: ios, core-data, gamekit

I've got a project that works where I'm sending 3 different NSManagedObjects (3 NSDictionaries) and receiving/storing properly in Core Data (Parent/Child).   The current solution is sending the Dicts individually (sendDataToAllPeers).  On the receipt side it appears to be taking about 10-30 seconds to arrive into didReceiveData, and then it processes one by one.  This is most likely due to the fact that I've stuffed image strings into 2 of the entities the payload is larger.  Regardless, what I'd like to achieve is a sold end user experience where it receives all at one time (I'll throw up a HUD for indicating its receiving/processing)...  Is there a Recommended way to bundle the entire payload of NSdicts and stream it over and of course Re-construct?  By the way I am NSCoding/Decoding.  A choppy User Experience I'm trying to make smooth.

Comment: I'm starting to think I may need to chunk my transmissions like this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877523/gamekit-bluetooth-transfer-problem.   I created an array of the 3 dicts, streamed it out and saved a file.. Size was 1.4 Meg..will update this post with my progress.

Comment: I found this by boreal which seems promising from a chunking perspective:  https://github.com/borealkiss/BKSessionController.  However, my original solution seems to be getting the data (sending and receiving individual Dicts),  What I'm looking for is more of a Synchronous solution where both phones are paused while it all processes.. Analogous to syncing your phone to iTunes w/tethered USB.  I'll post more as I progress, but I don't know if anyone else is reading :).

Comment: On to answering my own question :)

Comment: I've figured this out via borealkiss:  https://github.com/borealkiss/BKSessionController.  I recommend anyone wishing to do this sort of thing, to study this project.  I reached out to boreal kiss, and he wasn't really coding on iOS any longer.  If anyone wishes to ask me, I'll guide you on how I incorporated the chunking..